# Ruby, How can I compare two pair of items in array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a   array of hashes like :

```
arry = {hash1, hash2, hash3,hash4 ....hash_N}
```

for each hash,

```
hash1 ={ "deviceId"=>"868403021230682", "osVersion"=>"6.0", "deviceOS"=>"Android", 
"appVersion"=>"1.7.2", "action"=>"Enter"}
hash2 = { "deviceId"=>"868403021230682", "osVersion"=>"6.0", "deviceOS"=>"Android", 
"appVersion"=>"1.7.2", "action"=>"Leave"}
```

because it is possible that for each hash `"action"=>"Enter" or "Leave"` will not always appear as a pair , for example, **action**  for hash3, hash4,hash5 could be all **"Enter"** . My idea is only consider two hashes who can make a pair like hash1 and hash2,  remove other from array or put them into other array. 
   so the new array should just contain `[hash1, hash2, hash7,hash8]` , lets say hash7 and 8 are also a pair.

should I use each_with_index? my code is like this:

```
def get_result(doc)
result = []

doc.each_slice(2).map { |pair|
  pair.each_with_index { |element, index|
     if ( pair[index].has_value?([:action] => "enter") &&pair[index+1].has_value?([:action] => "Leave")
      result.push(pair)
     end
  }
}
end
```

but the `if` statement is not working right , kind of confused about how to use `each_with_index`   hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way your method is created , you can do it this way:

```
def get_result(doc)
   doc.each_sli­ce(2).to_a­.map{ |ah| ah if ah[0][:action] == 'Enter'­ && ah[1]­[:action] == 'Leave'­}.compact.flatten
end
```

**Explanation**

The variable `doc` is an array of hashes `[hash1, hash2, ...]` when we create `doc.each_slice(2).to_a` will return an array of pair of hashes `[[hash1, hash2],[hash3,hash4]...]`, Now when we do `map` and get the pair of hashes that has `actions` per order ('Enter','Leave') we get an array with nil values like this `[[hash1,hash2],nil,[hash5,hash6]..]` . we use compact to remove the `nil` values. now the array is like this `[[hash1,hash2],[hash5,hash6]..]` (array of pair of hashes) and the result expected is an array of hashes, that's why we need `flatten`, it will remove the inside array and return an array like this `[hash1, hash2, hash5, hash6 ...]`

If you need to get the list of deleted hashes, i think it would be better if add another method to do it. Otherwise, you can make the `get_result` method return two arrays.

Here is how you can do it :

```
def get_result(doc)
   removed_elms = []
   result = doc.each_sli­ce(2).to_a­.map do |ah| 
    # if you just need them different (not the first one 'Enter' and the second one 'Leave') you need to set the commented condition
    # if ['Enter','Leave'].include?(ah[0][:action] && ah[1][:action]) && ah[0][:action] != ah[1][:action]
    if ah[0][:action] == 'Enter'­ && ah[1]­[:action] == 'Leave' 
     ah
    else
     removed_elms << ah
     nil
    end
   end.compact
  [result.flatten, removed_elms.flatten]
end
```

Comment: how can I save the abandoned hashes to another array? why need flatten?  I only want to eliminate the hashes that are not paired. If possible would you mind explained a little? thank you

Comment: now I run into another problem, still confused about nested array of hashes.   I got the result with your code  which is [hash1, hash2, hash5, hash6 ...] , but what if the input is like [arry1, arry2,arry3.....]? I'm getting in ``[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`   error.

Comment: if `[array1, array2...]` is not a valid set of data you can add `if` condition `if ah[0].is_a?(Hash)` . otherwise , you need to define in which index the `:action` is, let's say the index is 2 , you can create `if (ah[0].is_a?(Array) && ah[0][2] == 'Enter' && ah[1][2] == 'Leave') || ( ah[0].is_a?(Hash) && ah[0][:action] == 'Enter' && ah[1][:action] == 'Leave')`